# About using the twelvefold way

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the following two problems:

- How many ways are there to distribute $5$ different books to $7$ students if each student gets no more than one book?

  Answer: $\frac{7!}{(7 - 5)!}$ by twelvefold way
- How many ways are there to distribute $12$ identical books to $10$ students?

  Answer: $\binom{12}{10}$ by twelvefold way

---

I was wondering what happens if $k$ and $n$ switch places in the problems above

- How many ways are there to distribute $7$ different books to $5$ students?
- How many ways are there to distribute $10$ identical books to $12$ students?

The answers $\frac{5!}{(5 - 7)!}$ and $\binom{10}{12}$ look wrong. I think in the first problem we should choose five books out of seven, then order them to get $\binom{7}{5}4!$ and in the second problem we choose ten students out of twelve to get $\binom{12}{10} = 66$ and to each of these sixty six $10$-groups we distribute ten identical book meaning $\binom{66}{10}$. Would this work? If not what works? Also, how does one verify one's solution to counting problems like this? Thanks.

Comment: The twelve identical books to ten students will not have an answer of $\binom{12}{10}$.  It will have an answer of $\left(\!\!\binom{12}{10}\!\!\right)$ or however else you choose to notate it, which simplifes to $\binom{12+10-1}{10-1}$, a very different answer, seen by stars-and-bars.

Comment: The answers are in some sense correct, provided you write the first as $7!\binom 5 7$. By convention $\binom n m = 0$ whenever $m > n > 0$. Also the answer is $0$ if you wan to distribute $7$ books to $5$ students and require that each student gets no more than $1$ book. Without that requirement, it's the stars-and-bars trick.

Comment: As for the word salad in your paragraph at the end... you are multiplying and counting things irrelevant to the problem.  $\binom{12}{10}$?  Why are we choosing ten students?  What do ten students have to do with anything here?  There are ten books, yes, but the books might have been distributed among fewer than ten students as well depending on how they are arranged.  We aren't told that no student may receive more than one book.  And then $\binom{66}{10}$?  Why are we choosing ten of the ways of selecting ten students?  This has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I see. Actually, ten identical books to twelve students is $\binom{12}{10}$. Ok, that's clear. Thank you.

Comment: @user732144 still not quite right.  Ten identical books to twelve distinct students *such that no student gets more than one book* is $\binom{12}{10}$.  Ten identical books to twelve distinct students where a student is *potentially allowed to get more than one book* has a different answer, namely $\binom{12+10-1}{10-1}$.  In your problem statements, you only stipulated that students may not receive more than one book in  your first problem, not in your second problem, so since it wasn't mentioned in the second problem we should assume that they *are* allowed more than one book each.

Comment: @WhatsUp, Can't we distribute any five books to five students with two left over? There would be $x$ ways of doing that. We could give three books to three students where there are $y$ ways of doing this. There are many other such possibilities? Would this get too complicated? What in the problem says we cannot do this? Thanks.

Comment: Good play.... so you allow two books to be left, not distributing to anyone...

Comment: @WhatsUp, I see, distributing $k$ objects means getting rid of all $k$ of them. This answers my last question. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, usually people understand it this way in this type of questions. "Distribute" means there is no left.